# Ordinary differential equation index error

Tags: python, indexing, scipy

I am beginning to learn Python (this is my first attempt at a python script). I'm trying to solve and then subsequently graph a series of differential equations which show how the concentrations of compounds in the following equation h2o+co2 <-> o2+ch2o are linked.

However when I run the script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

y=[3.0,1.0,3.0,1.0]
g=15 
i=25 
tspan= np.linspace(0,5,100)

# h2o+co2 <-> o2+ch2o
def chemanalysis(y,t):

    x =i*math.sin(math.pi*t/12)**2

    dydt= -x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3]) #co2
    dydt= -x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3]) #h2o
    dydt= x*(y[0]*y[1])  - g*(y[2]*y[3]) #o2
    dydt= x*(y[0]*y[1])  - g*(y[2]*y[3]) #ch2o


    return dydt


y=odeint(chemanalysis,1,tspan)

print(y)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "first.py", line 25, in <module>
        y=odeint(chemanalysis,1,tspan)
        ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
      File "first.py", line 16, in chemanalysis
        dydt= -x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3]) #co2
    IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I know this is probably an immensely straight forward issue brought about by my lack of experience in python/programming in general. I'd really appreciate any help on where I have gone wrong or where I can improve this code. I have read some other similar issues/error messages on other threads however I haven't been able to resolve the issue myself. I know there are no graphing components attached to this script currently, I figured I would wait until resolving this problem first.

Regards

Comment: When you give `1` as argument in `y=odeint(chemanalysis,1,tspan)`, you are giving an integer which is then considered as a list, as you want it to be actually in the function `chemanalysis`. Whence this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you want to do here:

Change `y=odeint(chemanalysis, 1, tspan)` to `y2=odeint(chemanalysis, y, tspan)`

and for [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) to work, you need to return a list of same size as `y`.

```
def chemanalysis(y,t):
    x =i*math.sin(math.pi*t/12)**2

    dydt = []

    dydt.append(-x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3])) #co2
    dydt.append(-x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3])) #h2o
    dydt.append(x*(y[0]*y[1])  - g*(y[2]*y[3])) #o2
    dydt.append(x*(y[0]*y[1])  - g*(y[2]*y[3])) #ch2o


    return dydt
```

We could make this look more pythonic, but omitting for brevity.

---

A little more explanation on why you need to use `append` in `chemanalysis`:

```
dydt= -x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3]) #co2
dydt= -x*(y[0]*y[1]) + g*(y[2]*y[3]) #h2o
dydt= x*(y[0]*y[1])  - g*(y[2]*y[3]) #o2
dydt= x*(y[0]*y[1])  - g*(y[2]*y[3]) #ch2o

return dydt
```

The above would just return `dydt` as the last assigned value which is `#ch2o`, you're losing out on the other data and rewriting `dydt` every time. Instead make it a list, which `odeint` requires you to do anyway.

Comment: Thanks so much for your super fast response. I understand why using y= was wrong however, would it be possible for you to tell me why you added the append to the function?

Comment: @AW1991 it's an implementation necessity of the odeint function https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html.

also when you're just assigning to `dydt` multiple times, you're just overwriting the variable and losing info.